# Is my PFET Orientation Correct for Reverse Voltage Protection?

Tags: mosfet

Do I have the P MOSFET orientation in the attached circuit correct?
[image: Reverse Voltage Protection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Is my PFET Orientation Correct for Reverse Voltage Protection?*

No it has drain and source connected incorrectly.

The easiest way to remember is that the MOSFET's bulk diode would not be reverse biased when the polarity is correct. Yours would be reverse biased as it currently stands. This is how it should be done especially if the input voltage can rise beyond 20 volts although the 100 Ω resistor can be significantly higher in value: -

[image]

Source: [PMOS MOSFET for Reverse Voltage Protection](https://components101.com/articles/design-guide-pmos-mosfet-for-reverse-voltage-polarity-protection) but, as with any circuit on the web, there are many examples that are wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  The zener is a good idea to protect against exceeding Vgs max.

Comment: @BarryJensen yes it is and doesn't really do any harm when the supply voltage doesn't exceed circa 20 volts. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: I accepted Andy Aka's answer, The body diode direction in his answer makes sense, compared to the body diode direction of an NFET used as a low side switch. one of these days, I'll get my hands on a PFET and breadboard it to prove it to myself.